# How can we distinguish between regular languages and context free languages?

Tags: regular-language, context-free-language

to express regular languages we use regexp and for context free languages we can use an stack-like memory, I know context free languages have some specifications like center embedding, but still I'm not sure when we can be confidant a given language is context free language? for example why does natural language is not a regular language. is there any reason except center embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automata theory states that a **regular language** can be processed by a Finite State Machine (FSM). However, if a language has "center-embedding", then that language is a **Context-Free Language(CFL)** which requires a Push-Down Automata(PDA).

Importantly, a PDA is a FSM with an additional resource of a memory-like device that is a "stack" or "counter" in order to keep track of the embeddings.

Wikipedia says in [Languages that are not context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Languages_that_are_not_context-free) :-

> To prove that a given language is not context-free, one may employ
>   `the pumping lemma` for context-free languages or a number of other
>   methods, such as `Ogden's lemma` or `Parikh's theorem`.

Wikipedia says in [Deciding whether a language is regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Deciding_whether_a_language_is_regular) :-

> To prove that a language is not regular, one often uses
>   the Myhill–Nerode theorem or the pumping lemma among other methods.

why does natural language is not a regular language ?

Chomsky said in (1957): “English is not a regular language”. As for context-free languages, “I do not know whether or not English is itself literally outside the range of such analyses”.

I am adding that `English is such a vast language which can't be recognised by a finite machine`.